# What is the anticipated usage of this Chinese textbook's long lists of questions and answers?

Tags: learning-methods, chinese, teaching-methods

The Chinese HSK6 textbook series 《HSK规范教程 6上》 by 王璕 has many pages like the following

> [image: photo of page 45 上册]

wherein there are many listed questions and answers, such as

> 最近一年你身边有什么**灾难**发生吗？
> In the previous year, has a disaster happened in your vicinity?
>
> 最近一年我身边有/没有灾难发生吗？
> In the previous year, a disaster has / hasn't happened in my vicinity.

I'm puzzled about how these are to be used.  I didn't find an explanation in the preface of the textbook.  Presumably it's to practice using the vocabulary in context, but I'm not sure precisely what to do with it.  Just read it?

**Question**: What is the anticipated usage of this Chinese textbook's long lists of questions and answers?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood this practice.
Actually,this practice is :
first ,it gives you an questions ; second,it offers you two kinds of answers :one answer is affirmative, the other one is negative.

So this practice is to make exercises how to answer the questions affirmatively and negatively.

For example:
Question:最近一年你身边有什么灾难发生吗？

Answer 1: 最近一年我身边有灾难发生. An affirmative answer

Answer 2: 最近一年我身边没有灾难发生.a negative answer.

Through these exercises above, it helps you perceive how to answer affirmatively or negatively properly.

Comment: I don't know Chinese but your explanation makes total sense.